# Lotusscript logic for repeating calendar options, but in separate app

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I need to use the "repeat options" subform in the mail file in an application that tracks our implementations.

I have looked at the code behind this in the mail file, but it is way too complex for my needs, as I just want the whole logic on how to get the various dates/times I need to create a document for.  I have seen some calls to a method, generateRepeatDatesExt(), but I did a search and couldn't find any trace of it.

Anyone knows where that thing is hidden?  Or better, anyone has a sample app that creates repeating dates that use the repeat options found in the mail file?

Any help, pointers, samples are welcomed!!!

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a really nice demo application that does exactly what I need, and it was done by Julian Robichaux a while back.  Details and sample file can be found here: http://www.nsftools.com/tips/NotesTips.htm#repeatdates

Comment: I just wanted to add a note of what I actually  had to do to make this work in a Notes 9.0.1 Environment...  In the existing form where I added the dialog box for the repeat options, I needed to add these 2 fields: $CSVersion and Chair.  I filled the first with "2" and the other one with the current user's name.  It now runs as smooth as a newborn's bottom!!!! (I have a new nephew so please forgive that reference)